# python: оптимизация размера словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, память, словари, dict

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Есть файл с записями вида:

```
строка:число
строка:число
...
строка:число
```

Мне необходимо перевести их в словарь, где строка - ключ, число - значение

Всего имею `56.280.820` записей, суммарным объёмом `1.318.795.472` байт.

И при доступных 16ГБ памяти (10, остальное остальные приложения и ОС кушают) я не могу сформировать словарь - программа падает в связи с расходом всей памяти

> MemoryError

Такой вопрос - можно ли это как-то побороть в лоб, т.е. как-то манипулируя словарем? Или просто такие объёмы данных не обрабатываемы при таком объёме памяти?

**P.S.**

саму задачу использования таких объёмов памяти я могу решить разбивая словарь на словари меньшего объёма и подгружая и используя их последовательно

т.е. оптимизировать задачу таким способом, но хотелось бы понять, неужто сам словарь занимает так много места в памяти? (в C++ вроде для std::map каждая запись требует минимум 20 байт, но это опять означало бы расходование 1ГБ памяти, что в рамках свободных 10ГБ не так и много)

**P.P.S.**

словари храню в zip архивах - чтобы места меньше занимали:
в качестве разделителя использую в данном случае '='

```
# распарсить словарь
def parse_dictionary(text, dictionary, separator = '\n'):
    data = text.split(separator)

    # распарсить данные
    size = 0

    for record in data:
        if record[:4] == "===>":
            size = int(record.split('=')[-1])

            if size not in dictionary:
                dictionary[size] = dict()
        elif size > 0:
            props = record.split('=')
            if len(props) == 2:
                dictionary[size][props[0]] = dictionary[size].get(props[0], 0) + int(props[1])

# загрузить словарь из zip файла
def zip2dictionary(path, dictionary):
    print(path)

    # загрузить данные
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path, 'r') as zip_object:
        # обработать каждый файл из архива
        for object in zip_object.filelist:
            with zip_object.open(object.filename) as file:
                # разархивировать файл
                text = file.read().decode("ansi")

                # распарсить данные
                parse_dictionary(text, dictionary)
```

словарь вида:

```
===> size=1
abate=201
accurse=133
afraid=3695
ago=3280
ah=5660
ahead=1397
aie=31
alarm-bell=3
alike=668
alive=2066
almost=8891
alone=8142
along=8532
altar=559
always=12844
among=9740
angel=1355
anger=1698
angle=535
angrily=639
another=15745
answer=12530
anything=8424
arm=11862
ask=20205
asleep=2080
avenue=785
away=21810
axe=392
back=24647
beast=2603
begin=17905
```

Comment: А пример данных привести? А код формирования словаря показать? Засада может быть где угодно. Да, и главное - зачем нужен этот словарь, как его потом планируется использовать?

Comment: можете привести в вопросе соответствующий код и более широкое описание задачи? Я надеюсь вы используете 64-битную версию Python?

Comment: Покажите код. Подозреваю что вы падаете на каком-то промежуточном этапе.

Comment: Загрузил аналогичный файл чуть большего размера: потребовалось 7.6GB памяти.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, верно, добавил код и пример данных

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, сомневаюсь - когда я разбивал словарь на 2 части (просто делил файл на 2 части) - то по отдельности за 2 запуска обе части обрабатывались, кроме того я посмотрел расход памяти и действительно выделенная память доходила до 16ГБ, после чего питон выдавал ошибку

Comment: @MaxU, надо проверить, но скорее всего - дело в том, что в менеджере ресурсов я видел, что память выедается вся, так что это все таки не вопрос 32 битной версии

Comment: @Zhihar, вы грузите файл целиком как одну строку (двойная память), разбиваете его на строки (одинарная память), и только потом строите словарь. Без первых двух этапов можно обойтись.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, загрузка и разбитие - это всего лишь 1-1,5ГБ, но тем не менее тоже чувствительно. А как можно обойтись без этого и желательно не в сильный ущерб скорости? Я просто пока не уловил вашу идею

Comment: Хм, в примерах строки с данными довольно короткие. Интересно, за счёт чего средняя длина строки выходит 23 тогда.

Comment: @Zhihar, после того, как вы показали код становится понятнее что происходит - вы читаете файл целиком в память и потом создаете дополнительные копии данных в функциях. Как вы используете получившийся словарь? Я бы не стал хранить такие данные в небинарном виде - т.е. в таком виде, который при каждом чтении нужно парсить - это занимает ресурсы. Я бы хранил словари в Pickle файле или как Pandas.DataFrame в виде Parquet файла. Но для того чтобы дать толковый совет, нужно понимать "use cases" - то как вы планируете использовать эти данные

Comment: @MaxU, да, действительно из-за загрузки файла в память целиком минимум на этапе загрузки и парсинга объем используемой памяти вырастает на объем файла, но если бы даже читать файл построчно, то описанная выше проблема возникла бы чуть позже, когда словарь увеличился бы (скажем в полтора раза), опять же - суммарный объем данных был 1,3ГБ, а заелось значительно больше и как я понимаю из-за того, как устроен словарь у питона. На счет `Pandas.DataFrame` - спасибо, посмотрю что это за зверь (никогда раньше не работал с этим)

Answer (score 3):

Сколько памяти нужно чтобы загрузить целиком текст из файла? Примерно два размера файла.

Еще один объём нужен чтобы затем порезать на строки.

Только потом вы начнёте строить словарь.

Файл - 1.5Gb. Лишняя память 4.5GB. Мои замеры показывают что сам словарь требует 7.6GB. В сумме вы вылезаете из 10GB.

Читайте строки напрямую. Скорость от это не пострадает, а памяти надо будет на 4.5GB меньше:

```
# f - открытый файл, не текст!!!
def parse_dictionary(f, dictionary):
    # распарсить данные
    size = 0

    for record in f:
        if record[:4] == "===>":
            size = int(record.split('=')[-1])

            if size not in dictionary:
                dictionary[size] = dict()
        elif size > 0:
            props = record.split('=')
            if len(props) == 2:
                dictionary[size][props[0]] = dictionary[size].get(props[0], 0) + int(props[1])
```

Читаем обычный файл:

```
with open(<filename>, 'r') as f:
    parse_dictionary(f, dictionary)
```

Читаем zip-архив:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'r') as zip_object:
    # обработать каждый файл из архива
    for obj in zip_object.filelist:
        with zip_object.open(obj.filename) as f:
            ff = (line.decode('ascii') for line in f)
            parse_dictionary(ff, dictionary)
```

Чтение обычного текстового файла с 56 миллионами записей требует на моём компьютере 46 секунд. Тот же файл из zip-архива читается за 93 секунды. Расход памяти одинаков - 7.6GB.

Comment: я понял вашу идею!
а для zip это сработает? там же `text = file.read().decode("ansi")` использую

Comment: Добавил пример чтения из zip.

Comment: парсить данные из текстовых файлов при каждом чтении - не самый лучший способ использования ресурсов. Лучше уж тогда хранить данные в бинарном виде. Но лучше все-таки подождать пока автор вопроса расскажет больше о том как планируется использовать данные.

Comment: @MaxU, сравниваю 2 словаря, нахожу слова в словаре 1, частота которых выше, чем слова в словаре 2 (если слова в словаре 2 отсутствуют, то их частота считается равной 0)

Comment: @Zhihar, для того, что вы пока описали - модуль Pandas подходит идеально. Он позволяет работать с табличными данными в категориях матриц и векторов. Т.е. вместо того, чтобы писать вложенные циклы вы оперируете сразу таблицами/матрицами/векторами. Код работает на порядки быстрее и выглядит гораздо проще и элегантнее )

Comment: @MaxU, понял, буду изучать, спасибо

Comment: @Zhihar  `сравниваю 2 словаря, нахожу слова в словаре 1, частота которых выше, чем слова в словаре 2` если строки отсортированы, как в примере, то и словари могут быть не нужны.

Answer (score 2):

Для объектов, занимающих много памяти часто используют [хеш](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) объекта вместо самого объекта:

```
data = {}

for line in file:
    text, number = line.strip().split(":")
    data[hash(text)] = float(number)
```

PS обычно хеш занимает до 36 байт памяти - разумеется хеш имеет смысл использовать если строки в среднем занимают намного больше памяти.

при поиске тоже следует использовать хеш строки:

```
res = data.get(hash(string_))
```

Comment: Оно да, но возможны же коллизии. Коллизии можно разрешить только имея исходную строку.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, теоретически это возможно. Можно использовать `MD5` хеш из  модуля `hashlib` - там вероятность коллизий будет очень низкой

Comment: Без знания что там за строки тут только гадать. Если строки короткие, то качественный длинный хэш наоборот раздует данные )  А вот если строки довольно длинные, то хороший хэш это выход, да

Comment: @CrazyElf, согласен! Чем больше информации о задаче в вопросе, тем более взвешенные и полезные советы можно дать

Comment: Средняя длина строки в файле - `23.43` символа. Сюда входят и само число и двоеточие и перевод строки. Строки короткие. Коллизий при нашей жизни не будет.

Comment: Попробовал на искусственных данных, вроде бы с `hash` раза в полтора-два меньше стало места есть, так что вариант вполне )

Comment: `разумеется хеш имеет смысл использовать если строки в среднем занимают намного больше памяти.`, нет, строки как раз занимают меньше места чаще всего или сопоставимо (это слова или фразы, а также частота их использования)

Comment: @MaxU, действительно с тем же MD5 все было бы понятно, но MD5 - это 16 байт, а строки у меня чаще меньшего размера, т.е. они сами для себя являются хорошим хэшом со 100% уникальностью :)

Comment: `согласен! Чем больше информации о задаче в вопросе, тем более взвешенные и полезные советы можно дать`

дополнил свой вопрос- по сути это список слов и фраз и частота их использования

Answer (score 2):

Ну, в общем, примерно так оно и занимает, порядок цифр у меня примерно такой же получился на искусственных данных. Объекты питона весьма не маленькие:

```
import sys
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

n = 56_280_820
k = 10**22 - 1
m = 0
d = {}
s = 0
for _ in tqdm(range(n)):
    d[str(k)] = m
    k -= 1
    m = (m + 1) % 10
    s += 22 + 1 + 1

print(f'Размер данных в исходных символах: {s}')
dict_size = sum(sys.getsizeof(key) + sys.getsizeof(val) for key,val in d.items())
print(f'Словарь занимает: {dict_size}, элемент занимает: {dict_size//n}')
print(f'Примерный размер данных, которые должны быть в одном элементе словаря: {sum(map(sys.getsizeof, ("123", hash("123"), 1)))}')
```

Вывод:

```
Размер данных в исходных символах: 1350739680
Словарь занимает: 5549288852, элемент занимает: 98
Примерный размер данных, которые должны быть в одном элементе словаря: 116
```

То есть оно ещё как-то даже экономит место. Подозреваю на том, что хэш не хранится, хэш это адрес, по которому нужно данные положить. А так питон очень не экономный язык, особенно если разнородные данные в родных питоновских объектах хранить. Тут получилось, что порядка 100 байт на один элемент уходит: строка + хэш + int очень много занимает в питоне.

Comment: У вас в значениях цифры. А цифры (маленькие целые) Питон кеширует: `a = 9; id(9) == id(1 * a)` -> `True`. Большие - нет: `a = 9; id(999) == id(111 * a)` -> `False`. Более реалистичный пример будет с большими значениями.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я знаю. Я пробовал уже другие варианты с более длинными числами, ничего вроде не поменялось. Т.е. на этом экономии нет. И мы не знаем, какие числа у автора вопроса.